# Method (Inheritance) and overriding in Rust

Tags: rust

```
use crate::size::Size;

pub struct Car {
    pub name: String,
    pub color: (u32, u32, u32),
    pub size: Size,
    pub model: u32,
    pub private: i32,
}

impl Car {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Car {
            name: String::from("Default Template"),
            color: (1, 0, 1),
            size: Size::NORMAL,
            model: 2019,
            private: 2,
        }
    }
}
pub trait CommontMethods {
    fn change_name_and_model(&mut self, private: i32);
}

pub trait PrintChanges {
    fn print_changes(&self);
}

impl CommontMethods for Car {
    fn change_name_and_model(&mut self, private: i32) {
        println!("{}", self.name);
        self.model = 2000;
        self.private = private;
        self.print_changes();
    }
}

impl PrintChanges for Car {
    fn print_changes(&self) {
        println!("Model :{} , private : {}", self.model, self.private);
    }
}
```

This is the `Car` struct it has the a `_name_and_model()` function that calls `print_changes()`. The `Honda` struct that has a field `car : Car {...}`

When calling `honda.change_name_and_model()`, I want it to actually call the `print_changes()` function that is implemented in Honda not Car.

```
use crate::car::*;
use crate::size::Size;

pub struct Honda {
    pub car: Car,
    lights_on: bool,
}

impl Honda {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Honda {
            car: Car {
                name: String::from("Honda"),
                color: (1, 1, 1),
                size: Size::BIG,
                model: 2002,
                private: 3,
            },
            lights_on: true,
        }
    }
}

impl PrintChanges for Honda {
    fn print_changes(&self) {
        self.car.print_changes();
        println!("this is usefull !");
    }
}
```

So when i want to use this like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut honda = Honda::new();

    honda.car.change_name_and_model(0);
}
```

The `change_name_and_model()` function calls the car implementation of `print_changes()`, but I want it to call Honda one instead.

Is that even possible ?

Comment: Rust isn't Java. Don't try to emulate Java.

Comment: yes but how i do this in rust without duplicated code ?

Comment: Do what exactly? Your real goal is to build features, not to model a domain's data according to an OO hierarchy of objects. Because Rust isn't an OO language. I honestly don't see exactly what would be the best lead. Maybe start with simple programs and try to form a vision on how to design a complex program ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret rust has everything an OO language needs, namely encapsulation and polymorphism. It doesn't use inheritance but that's hardly a defining feature of an OO language.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. OP's question is precisely about inheritance.

Comment: @DenysSéguret OP's question is about polymorphism rather than inheritance.

Comment: Honda and Honda::car are two different entities. Honda contains a Car but is not a Car. There is no "is a" relationship between structs in Rust, only between traits. The simplest way to do what you want is to combine changing and printing changes in a single trait, and implement that trait for both Car and Honda. You don't have to duplicate the code. You may have to call a Car implementation from a Honda implementation. If you want to keep two separate traits, you will need two separate trait objects, one for CommonMethods and one for PrintChanges.

Comment: I see on a lot of comments on Rust posts people asserting things to the effect, "why are you trying to do OO? Rust isn't OO." This is false. Rust is multi-paradigm and if you prefer an OO approach to software development, have at it. You can apply your OO skills you gained with Java or other languages with Rust. Any of the popular OO design patterns are possible with Rust. Iterators in fact are an OO abstraction which Rust uses heavily.

Comment: Regarding inheritance, Rust does have it - just not in the same way you expect from Java or C++. Traits can inherit from other traits, data can't be inherited, but methods can. The methods can in fact have default implementations too. And if you needed a base trait to have state, there are some tricks that can make it possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pardon my bit of OO redesign here. I'm going to make `Car` my base "class" - or trait, that `Honda` and `Chevrolet` inherit from.

If you're coming from Java, think of traits as interfaces - or abstract classes. Since traits can contain default implementations for methods, they're more like abstract classes - except they can't have data members.

Let's say that `Car` inherits from another trait, `PrintsUpdate`. Which means `Honda` and `Chevrolet` also have to implement it (or if `PrintsUpdate` has a default implementation, overriding it is optional).

If we do everything right, we can get the polymorphic behavior we want. For instance we can write functions that take a pointer to the `Car` trait and invoke their methods, and observe that the correct overriding implementation gets called.

```rust
pub fn polymorphism_test()
{
    let mut honda = Honda::new("Civic", "Foolton", "Blue");
    let mut chevy = Chevrolet::new("Corvette", "Barbie", "Red");
    
    update_car(&mut honda, "Bazner", "Green");
    update_car(&mut chevy, "Quxner", "Orange");
}

pub fn update_car(car: &mut dyn Car, owner: &str, color: &str) {
    println!("Updating a {}...", car.make());
    car.update(owner, color);
}
```

output:

```
Updating a Honda...
Printing changes for Bazner's Green Honda Civic
Updating a Chevrolet...
Printing changes for Quxner's Orange Chevrolet Corvette
```

Here are our base traits. I have `Car` inheriting from `PrintsUpdate`:

```rust
pub trait Car: PrintsUpdate {
    fn make(&self) -> &str;
    fn set_owner(&mut self, name: &str);
    fn set_color(&mut self, name: &str);
    fn update(&mut self, owner: &str, color: &str)
    {
        self.set_owner(owner);
        self.set_color(color);
        self.print_changes();
    }
    //fn print_changes(&self);
}

pub trait PrintsUpdate {
    fn print_changes(&self) {
        println!("Default implementation for PrintsUpdate...");
    }
}
```

Note that in `Car::update()` methods are being invoked that aren't implemented yet. This is fine. `Chevrolet` and `Honda` will have to implement them if they inherit `Car`.

Here's our `Honda` "class":

```rust
pub struct Honda {
    make: String,
    model: String,
    owner: String,
    color: String,
}
impl Honda {
    pub fn new(model: &str, owner: &str, color: &str) -> Self {
        Honda { 
            make : "Honda".into(), model: model.into(), 
            owner: owner.into(),   color: color.into() 
        }
    }
}

impl Car for Honda {
    fn make(&self) -> &str {
        &self.make
    }
    fn set_owner(&mut self, name: &str) {
        self.owner = name.into();
    }
    fn set_color(&mut self, color: &str) {
        self.color = color.into();
    }
}
impl PrintsUpdate for Honda {
    fn print_changes(&self) {
        println!("Printing changes for {}'s {} Honda {}", 
                 self.owner, self.color, self.model);
    }
}
```

And `Chevrolet`:

```rust
pub struct Chevrolet {
    make: String,
    model: String,
    owner: String,
    color: String,
}
impl Chevrolet {
    pub fn new(model: &str, owner: &str, color: &str) -> Self {
        Chevrolet { 
            make : "Chevrolet".into(), model: model.into(), 
            owner: owner.into(),       color: color.into() 
        }
    }
}
impl Car for Chevrolet {
    fn make(&self) -> &str {
        &self.make
    }
    fn set_owner(&mut self, name: &str) {
        self.owner = name.into();
    }
    fn set_color(&mut self, color: &str) {
        self.color = color.into();
    }
}
impl PrintsUpdate for Chevrolet {
    //fn print_changes(&self) {
    //    println!("Printing changes for {}'s {} Chevrolet {}", 
    //             self.owner, self.color, self.model);
    //}
}
```

If `Chevrolet` chooses not to override `PrintsUpdate::print_changes()` that's fine because there's a default implementation for it. The output at the top is what it looks like if `Chevrolet::prints_changes()` isn't commented out. Below is with it commented out.

Running the `polymorphism_test()` function again, we get:

```
Updating a Honda...
Printing changes for Bazner's Green Honda Civic
Updating a Chevrolet...
Default implementation for PrintsUpdate...
```